How to enable VNC over labwc
I finally decided to adopt Bookworm on my older Pi.
I did a fresh install of Raspbian GNU/Linux 12 (bookworm) on my Pi2 and got it running without many issues.
Unfortunately when trying to convert my Pi3 or Pi3B+ Bookworm installations (running X desktop) to labwc I could not get VNC working.

I think I have finally got it working, and the problem seemed to be that wayvnc.service was not starting.
I have since found others with similar problems so thought the following may help.

Disable VNC in raspi-config.
Enable labwc
Reboot (may not be necessary)
Enable VNC in raspi-config.

sudo systemctl status wayvnc.service should then show it working, and it is possible to connect with RealNVC viewer or Raspberry Pi Connect.

There are still a few issues with labwc;
It does not currently seem to be possible to change button-layout (which you could before with gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences);
The cursor only seems to support a small dot (although the normal pointer on your host should work);
Dragging icons often seems to hijack the pointer (although this may be related to "You need to start dragging as soon as you have clicked the icon. If you click and hold without moving the icon, the gesture recogniser for long hold on a touch screen is triggered, which then simulates a right-click.")
